# Two websites on one server, why does reaching the server IP ends up on one of these websites instead of root?

Tags: apache, webserver

I have an Apache server, on which I have associated two domains, say `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`, and separated their codebase like this:

```
var/www/html/
        |
        |
        ---- domain1.com/
        |    |
        |    |___ index.html
        |         ... other site content
        |
        ---- domain2.com/ 
        |    |
        |    |___ index.html
        |         ... other site content
```

In `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`, I've specified the two implementations:

**domain1.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1.com
    ServerName domain1.com
</VirtualHost>
```

**domain2.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2.com
    ServerName domain2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I have then enabled both websites:

```
a2ensite domain1.com.conf domain2.com.conf
systemctl reload apache2
```

So everything works fine, when I go to `domain1.com` I see what's expected, and same when I go to `domain2.com`, but when I reach my server's IP with a web browser, I'm being presented the content of `domain1.com` (I would like to add that the content of `domain2.com` is protected with a .htaccess/.htpasswd combination, and not `domain1.com`).
Is there a reason for this?

Thank you for your help

Comment: "*If no matching ServerName or ServerAlias is found in the set of virtual hosts containing the most specific matching IP address and port combination, then the first listed virtual host that matches that will be used*" https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html#alg

Answer (score 0):

When a domain is asked for by the browser, Apache looks at the domain and matches it with one of the VirtualHost definitions (ServerName or ServerAlias). If none match, it will use the first VirtualHost it found in the configurations, thus domain1 for you. Apache can split between domains if you ask for one.

By IP it does not know which one you want, unless you define 1 domain == 1 ip on your server.

You could setup a default VirtualHost present before your domain1 to overwrite this behavior.